# variable parameter for sql parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm accessing a stored procedure and I'm trying to pass some parameters to it. I have the following loop that adds all parameters:

```
List<string> paramNames = new List<string> { 
        "@EmployeeId", 
        "@Location", 
        "@StartYear", 
        "@EndYear", 
        "@Department", 
        "@Title", 
        "@FileName"  
};

List<string> paramValues = new List<string> { 
        EmployeeId, 
        Location, 
        StartYear, 
        EndYear, 
        Department, 
        Title, 
        FileName 
};

// Add the input parameter and set its properties.
SqlParameter parameter;
for (int i = 0; i < paramNames.Count(); i++)
{
   parameter = new SqlParameter();
   parameter.ParameterName = paramNames[i];
   parameter.Value = paramValues[i];
   command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
}
```

the first parameter is "EmployeeId" and this value is coming from the method arguments. This parameter can either be a string value "All" or it can be an int value with the employee id.

-How do I pass its value to the stored procedure so it accepts a string or an int.

-And how do I tell it that if its "All" then I want all employees, otherwise if its a number, I want the employee with that number ID?

Comment: *As a side note,* instead of maintaining two lists, use `Dictionary<string,string>` for your parameters and their values, or better `List<SqlParameter>` where you can also specify the type of parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your stored procedure has a condition similar to

```
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = @EmployeeId
```

Change it to

```
WHERE @EmployeeId = 'All' OR EMPLOYEE_ID = @EmployeeId
```

This is a 'catch all' condition. If you pass 'All' - first part will be true and condition passes. Otherwise value of the parameter will be verified against table field

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using "All" you could simply just use a value of -1 or 0 for EmployeeId and then check for 0 or -1 in your stored procedure to return all users in that scenario.